# Same background for TextView and Button but different size

Tags: android, button, textview

In a LinearLayout,there is a TextView and Button ,both of them have a same drawable for background,
and their layout_width and layout_height are both wrap_content,but ,why the button is bigger than textview?

Comment: Add output image. It may the reason of paddings.

Comment: Please post your xml

Answer (score 2):

wrap_content means wrap the conent of that component so when the textView is empty it is smaller than the button which has text in it.

Try to make the text in the button shorter and you'll see it will be smaller.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have given text size or text appearance for the button...if you have given these then remove them....you will see the difference....
Just guessing your layout.....Hope this helps you